# React/Redux - when switching between routes content rendering is with delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm a beginner with reactjs/redux and I have a bug that I cant fix.

There is a bug between 2 routes that are rendering different data from the database.

**/dashboard** route is rendering component that is fetching user.products

**/products**  route is rendering component that is fetching all.products

So basically on the dashboard route you should see only those products that you have uploaded and on the products route you can see all the uploaded products from all the users.

The problem is whenever you switch between those two routes the content is rendering with a delay. When you are routing from `/products` to `/dashboard` for a fraction you will see on your dashboard all of products and then it will re-render correctly

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQRgu.gif)

**Dashboard component renders ProductsList:**

```
class ProductsList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProduct();
  }
render() {
    return <div>{this.renderProducts()}</div>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ products }) {
  return { products };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchProduct },
)(ProductsList);
```

**Products component renders AllProductsList:**

```
class AllProductsList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchAllProduct();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.renderProducts()}</div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ allproducts }) {
  return { allproducts };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchAllProducts },
)(AllProductsList);
```

When loading `/dashboard` page the `props.products` appears as empty array and after the fetch is done it fills this array.

When I route from `/dashboard` to `/products` page the `props.allproducts` at first is filled with data that was fetched for `products` and after the `fetchAllProducts()` is done it changes

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAGiO.png)

Comment: does your fetch functions do a http call?

Comment: so same api been used , the response json has any property that holds whether these are the products selected or uploaded by user ?

Comment: i think the issue is you are switching the route before the fetch is resolved, you can switch after the fetch updates the state.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS

There are two seperate APIs
    `module.exports = app => {
     app.get("/api/product", async (req, res) => {
     const products = await Product.find({ _user: req.user.id });
     res.send(products);
     });
     app.get("/api/allproducts", async (req, res) => {
     const allProducts = await Product.find({});
     res.send(allProducts);
      });`

Comment: so products is the reducer , are you holding two api responses in same variable or different variable ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Two api responses are held in same variable

Comment: @MattisRätsep so thats why for a fraction of second you are seeing the previous api data. Why can't hold the second api response in a different variable

Comment: @MattisRätsep can you post the action and reducer on the question.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Thank you for your support, with your questions I actually found where it went wrong. I just made 2 seperate reducers to handle this. Thanks again for your investigation it really helped me to find the answer

Comment: @MattisRätsep Welcom mattis , i have posted the answer you can check it. If it solved your issue please respond. So the future persons can check the answer and solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the two apis you are holding the same variable. So that's why for a fraction of second you are seeing the productsList data of users when you load the AllProducts component, vice versa.

The fraction of second is the time where the API takes to resolve or reject. Or perhaps should say as pending state of API.

I hope this can lead to your question and solve the issue.

Please let me know if any thing addition required to the post.

Answer (score -1):

`componentDidMount() {}` change to `componentWillMount(){}`

Problem is that you have delay between fetchRequest and API response, also keep in mind that you need time to update store and render products.

In your way you willn't get products till store not be changed.